# Backslash character remains on final string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and struggled on this issue:

I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup to **scrape** a page and get a url. When printing **url_imagem** it's shown on console without any backslash escape char, but on my final JSON it remains on the string.

```
                images_ = container_.find_all('div', class_='picture ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted')
                list_url = []
                for image in images_:
                    url_imagem_ = image.img.get('src')
                    list_url.append(url_imagem_)
                
                url_imagem.append(list_url)
                print(url_imagem)
```

DataFrame to JSON:

```
with open('df.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    df.to_json('../Files/myFile.json', force_ascii=False, orient='records')
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: you can use `lines=True` or replace it via `replace('\','')`

Comment: something like `(orient='records').replace('\', '')`